# How to resolve the location symbol in import for google map

Tags: android, google-maps, fusedlocationproviderapi, location-services

I am trying to get my location on `Android Studio` using `GoogleMap` but I can not `import gms.location`.

getting error

> cannot resolve the symbol location.

And some codes are deprecated. like `setOnMyLocationChangeListener`.

`import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;`

`import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;`

`import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;`

`import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;`

Comment: What dependencies you are using for location in gradle ? Add with question ..

Comment: please add `app/build.gradle` file

Answer (score 0):

Add your app build.gradle

```
implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```